# Why isn't EntityFramework adding my objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, dbcontext

I'm populating an in-memory database with [AutoBogus](https://github.com/nickdodd79/AutoBogus) test data like this:

```
// Create dummy data.
var goalFaker = new AutoFaker<Goal>()
    .RuleFor(g => g.Id, f => f.IndexFaker + 1); // +1 for the non-zero primary key.
var goals = goalFaker.Generate(10);

// Use a dummy in-memory database instead of a real one.
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GoalContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDatabase")
    .Options;

// Save our dummy data to our dummy database.
using (var context = new GoalContext(options))
{
     context.AddRange(goals);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, the data never saves! It's completely ignored.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I get my test data to persist for the test?**

Answer (score -1):

The issue I had is that `Goal` is an abstract class. Once I switched to dummying the concrete implementation the problem went away.

```
// Create dummy data.
var goalFaker = new AutoFaker<SmartGoal>() // <--- Swap in concrete SmartGoal for abstract Goal.
    .RuleFor(g => g.Id, f => f.IndexFaker + 1);
var goals = goalFaker.Generate(10);

// Use a dummy in-memory database instead of a real one.
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GoalContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDatabase")
    .Options;

// Save our dummy data to our dummy database.
using (var context = new GoalContext(options))
{
     context.AddRange(goals);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That was fast..

Comment: @CaiusJard I used the "Answer my own question" option, so that's natural.